# Oracle SQL - Rearrange a Formerly Pivoted Table

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table :

```
+-----------+---------------+------------------+
|    ID     |     Rule 1    | Rule 2  | Rule 3 |
+-----------+---------------+------------------+
| ID001     | PASSED        | FAILED  | PASSED |
| ID002     | FAILED        | FAILED  | FAILED |
| ID003     | FAILED        | PASSED  | PASSED |
+-----------+---------------+---------+--------+
```

I wanted to transform it to have failed IDs under each rule..

expected result as below :

```
+-----------+---------+--------+
| Rule 1    | Rule 2  | Rule 3 |
+-----------+---------+--------+
| -         | ID001   | -      |
| ID002     | ID002   | ID002  |
| ID003     | -       | -      |
+-----------+---------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional statements:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Rule1 = 'FAILED' THEN ID END AS Rule1,
       CASE WHEN Rule2 = 'FAILED' THEN ID END AS Rule2,
       CASE WHEN Rule3 = 'FAILED' THEN ID END AS Rule3
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f8f97c43b9035e6795d65e9f8ef7de52)</kbd>